# Call a function from another class by clicking a button PyQt4

Tags: python, function, class, pyqt4

I have a checkbox and a run button. When the checkbox is checked, I want to run some functions by clicking the button. The problem is that the function is in another class outside the button's class. My example codes are as below.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Tab1Widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.Tab1Widget1initUI()

    def Tab1Widget1initUI(self):
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())

        self.T1W1checkBox1 = QCheckBox('a', self)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.T1W1checkBox1, 1, 0)

    def run(self):
        if self.T1W1checkBox1.isChecked() == True:
            pass

class Tab1Layout(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QGridLayout())

        self.group1 = Tab1Widget1(self)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.group1, 0, 0)

        btn = QPushButton('Run', self)
        self.layout().addWidget(btn, 1, 0)
        btn.clicked.connect(Tab1Widget1().run())  ##the problem is in this line.

class Page1(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Page1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tab1 = Tab1Layout()
        self.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")

        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.addTab(self.tab3, "Tab3")
        self.tab2_initUI()
        self.tab3_initUI()

    def tab2_initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.tab2.setLayout(grid)

    def tab3_initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.tab3.setLayout(grid)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 600, 370)
        self.startPage1()

    def startPage1(self):
        x = Page1(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Auto Benchmark")
        self.setCentralWidget(x)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, I want to run the "run" function in "Tab1Widget1" class. However, the button is in "Tab1Layout" class. 
When I run the codes, it returns to me "TypeError: connect() slot argument should be a callable or a signal, not 'NoneType'"

If anyone knows how to solve this, pls let me know. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in connecting any callable to a button click regardless of what object it is in.  But your code has two specific problems.  You write

```
 btn.clicked.connect(Tab1Widget1().run())
```

The first problem here is that `Tab1Widget1()` is creating a new `Tab1Widget1` but presumably you don't want that.  You want to call `run` on the `Tab1Widget1` you have already created and stored in `self.group`.

The second problem is that when you connect a signal you need to connect it to a callable: the method you want to call.  Instead here you are *calling* the `run` method at connect time and trying to connect to the *result* of that call (which is `None`).  So you are trying to connect the signal to `None` which will of course fail.  You need to refer to the method without calling it: just remove the calling brackets.

Putting it together:

```
  btn.clicked.connect(self.group1.run)
```

That seems to work.

Comment: Thanks!! I still have a question. When I remove the brackets, it did run through. But when I check the checkbox and press the run button, nothing will happen (I know in the "run" function it is a "pass", but if you replace it with print ('something'), it will not work). If u know how to solve it, pls let me know too thanks :)

Comment: Oh I didn't. I deleted but forgot to replace it in .connected. Thanks!!